# I have upload feature on my website using PHP. What i want is after uploading, is there a way that i can view it online, like on facebook?

Tags: php, html, facebook

Anyone can provide a tutorial or any links on how to view the uploaded .doc files online? Any info will be appreciated. thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.domain.com/path_to_your_document/name_of_document.doc
```

On a side note, you may wish to use Google Drive for sharing such a document.